# what is the biggest chainring I can put on my mountain bike?

Tags: crankset, chainring

I am going to do a 'gravel grind' ride with lots of elevation gain and want to be able to keep up with the cyclocross bike riders. From what I understand they have 46/36 chainrings.
My mountain bike came with 36/22 rings. 104/64 bcd crank. 10 speed cassette. I would like to run a 44/30 or 42/28. Does a 44 or 42 tooth 104bcd chainring exist that fits a 2x (and not 3x) crank?
My bike is a specialized crave. I would put on a 40t chainring or consider going to a triple crank.
Or could I put a road crankset on? My bottom bracket is 73mm gxp.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a crank that's easy to replace, like Shimano Hollowtech 2? It's actually easier to exchange those than chainrings. I usually ride a road-compact (50,34), but for long tours around the alps I exchange them for a MTB one (44,34,24). I have a non-indexed front-shifter, so I don't need to change settings. Triple crankset axis seem to be some 3mm longer than double road cranksets, don't know about double MTB - double road difference.

Anyway, beware that you might need to change the derailleur distance to bottom bracket - 44 chainrings are quite a big larger than 36 ones. With that comes readjusting the cable.

However, do you really need a bigger ring to keep up? I don't know your exact wheel size, but with 2m circumference at 36/11, 90 rpm you do about 35km/h

Answer (score 0):

If Google down for you?

http://www.raceface.com/components/rings/rings/evolve-10speed-ring/[Evolve 10 Speed 42t outer](http://www.raceface.com/components/rings/rings/evolve-10speed-ring/)

Comment: Will this work on a double? I bought a shimano ring that looks just like the one from the link and it turns out to be a triple... hard for me to tell from reading the websites, they don't seem to say if they are double or triple rings.

Comment: A double chainring is different than a triple?  News to me.

Comment: Back when 42/52 chainrings existed Shimano had different 52's to be matched with 42 and 39 small ring. Apparently the difference was in ramps and pins. Anyway, it's easy to find MTB chainrings up to 46t, the question is whether the front derailleur and frame fit.